# Vim Swap File Became 187 GB, What are Possible Explanations?

Tags: swap-file

I am running an Ubuntu Subsystem for Windows 10. Within Ubuntu, I worked on a small file via vim and backgrounded it (`CTRL-Z`) and foregrounded it (`% job #`) multiple times over a couple day period. Out of nowhere I was alerted by Windows to running out of Disk Space. Upon investigating, it turned out the swap file for the file I worked on had grown to 187 GB.

From what I understand, vim creates a swap file to keep track of changes in the event that it crashes; but, there's no way it could have contained that many changes! For my own edification/knowledge, I am hoping to get possible explanations for how this could have happened. Ideally, I could then try to recreate it.

Comment: Probably a buggy implementation in WSL of something that Vim relies on. Best file a bug report on MS's GitHub repo for WSL.